# How to find references to dates in natural text?

Tags: nlp, machine-learning, information-extraction, named-entity-recognition, temporal

What I want to do is to parse raw natural text and find all the phrases that describe dates.

I've got a fairly big corpus with all the references to dates marked up:

```
I met him <date>yesterday</date>.
Roger Zelazny was born <date>in 1937</date>
He'll have a hell of a hangover <date>tomorrow morning</date>
```

I don't want to interpret the date phrases, just locate them. The fact that they're dates is irrelevant (in real life they're not even dates but I don't want to bore you with the details), basically it's just an open-ended set of possible values. The grammar of the values themselves can be approximated as context-free, however it's quite complicated to build manually and with increasing complexity it gets increasingly hard to avoid false positives.

I know this is a bit of a long shot so I'm not expecting an out-of-the-box solution to exist out there, but what technology or research can I potentially use?

Comment: See question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294926/how-does-apple-find-dates-times-and-addresses-in-emails.  This is called Named Entity Extraction, as a subtask in Information Extraction. @reseter provided the link. Both machine learning as well as grammar-based approaches work well.

Comment: have a look at https://duckling.wit.ai/

Comment: @sdream Thanks, this looks promising too, I'm going to give it a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the generic approaches used in academia and in industry is based on Conditional Random Fields. Basically, it is a special probabilistic model, you train it first with your marked up data and then it can label certain types of entities in a given text.

You can even try one of the systems from Stanford Natural Language Processing Group: [Stanford Named Entity Recognizer](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml)

When you download the tool, note there are several models, you need the last one:

> Included with the Stanford NER are a 4 class model trained for CoNLL,
>   a 7 class model trained for MUC, and a 3 class model trained on both
>   data sets for the intersection of those class sets.
>
> 3 class   Location, Person, Organization
>
> 4 class   Location, Person, Organization, Misc
>
> **7 class Time, Location, Organization, Person, Money, Percent, Date**

**Update.** You can actually try that tool [online here](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/process). Select the `muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz` classifier and try some text with dates. It doesn't seem to recognize "yesterday", but it recognizes "20th century", for example. In the end, this is a matter of CRF training.

---

[image: Stanford NER screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, this looks very promising.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind CRFs are rather slow to train and require human-annotated data, so doing it yourself is not easy. Read the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294926/how-does-apple-find-dates-times-and-addresses-in-emails) for another example of how people often do it in practice- not much in common with current academic research.

Comment: Every algorithm will need some human-annotated data to start with... if computers could classify themselves there would be no need in any of those algorithms =)

Comment: But different algos have different characteristics with regards to the training performance as well as applicability, data formats and error rates, so +1 for a good option to consider.

Comment: It's definitely something I will try as well, luckily I have thousands of hand-annotated files so there's a lot of data to play around with. Error rates are likely to decide between the different methods.

Comment: Is anyone aware of work comparing the two approaches? I'd really like to know what the recall of the regex method is like.