# Find specific patteren of string in text

Tags: string, algorithm, pattern-matching, text-mining, string-search

I'm searching for a way to find some specific patterens in text. For example if I would like to find all references from a text in format like this:

- Baron, Naomi (2000) Alphabet to Email: How Written English Evolved and Where It's Heading, Routledge: London and New York.

So anything similar to this would be returned from input text. Is there any algorithm that is good with this. All I found so far was algorithm for searching similar strings in text.

I was thinking about using regular expressions, but I don't know if it is the best way to do it, because I would need something that would calculate some index of similarity and would then return hits that have best score.

Comment: What language? Sounds like you need something like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)

Comment: Describe what you are looking for better - try to describe the [grammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) with more then example. Once you do it - it'll be clear if regex is enough, or maybe you need a [context-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language) parser (and which: [LR? SLR?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) maybe [LL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser)?)

Comment: Parsing these strings are computing similarity are two distinct tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The technique your are looking for is called Information Extraction.

Here is my answer to a similar question:

[How does Apple find dates, times and addresses in emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294926/how-does-apple-find-dates-times-and-addresses-in-emails/9344555#9344555)

You might need to combine some Named Entity Recognition too. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition