# algorithm to detect time, date and place from invitation text

Tags: algorithm, api, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I am researching some Natural Language Processing algorithms to read a piece of text, and if the text seems to be trying to suggest a meeting request, it sets up that meeting for you automatically.

For example, if an email text reads:

> Let's **meet tomorrow** someplace in **Downtown at 7pm**".

The algorithm should be able to detect the Time, date and place of the event.

Does someone know of some already existing NLP algorithms that I could use for this purpose? I have been researching some NLP resources (like [NLTK](http://nltk.org) and [some tools in R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html)), but did not have much success.

Thanks

Comment: Why did I get a "-2" for my question? When one downvotes a question, can they also tell us the right way to do things so that it facilitates learning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294926/how-does-apple-find-dates-times-and-addresses-in-emails

Comment: @Darth.Vader I didn't downvote, but nobody needs to inform. But  let me just say, your post is just a resource request, which can get closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an application of [information extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_extraction), and can be solved more specifically with sequence segmentation algorithms like hidden Markov models (HMMs) or conditional random fields (CRFs).

For a software implementation, you might want to start with the [MALLET toolkit](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/) from UMass-Amherst, it's a popular library that implements CRFs for information extraction.

You would treat each token in a sentence as something to be labeled with the fields you are interested in (or 'x' for none of the above), as a function of word features (like part of speech, capitalization, dictionary membership, etc.)... something like this:

```
token       label       features
-----------------------------------
Let         x           POS=NNP, capitalized
's          x           POS=POS
meet        x           POS=VBP
tomorrow    DATE        POS=NN, inDateDictionary
someplace   x           POS=NN
in          x           POS=IN
Downtown    LOCATION    POS=NN, capitalized
at          x           POS=IN
7pm         TIME        POS=CD, matchesTimeRegex
.           x           POS=.
```

You will need to provide some hand-labeled training data first, though.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look to http://opennlp.apache.org java toolkit

Comment: Thanks, but open nlp does not support date-time/place entity recognition.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do this with spacy.
I tried this in jupyter-notebook

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

doc = nlp(u'Over the last quarter in 2018-12-02 Apple sold nearly 20 thousand iPods for a profit of $6 million.')
displacy.render(doc, style='ent', jupyter=True)
```

> Output

```
Over the last quarter DATE in 2018-12-02 DATE Apple ORG sold nearly 20 thousand CARDINAL iPods PRODUCT for a profit of $6 million MONEY .
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is still in the headlines today. If you are (still) looking for an algorithm, there are solutions using ANTLR a parser generator in a large choice of programming languages (C/C++/C#/JS/Java/...).
Some open-source references:

- http://natty.joestelmach.com/doc.jsp
- https://blog.dgunia.de/2017/08/18/using-antlr-to-parse-date-ranges-in-java-and-kotlin/
- https://github.com/eib/java-date-parser