# How to parse: in one week into a date?

Tags: python, nlp

How can I parse NLP labeled date strings into a certain date?

For example: Meeting with John in one week and 2 days.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084585/algorithm-to-detect-time-date-and-place-from-invitation-text